# Trouble finding difference of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: Let 
\begin{align*}
A &= \{a, b, c, d, e\} \\
B &= \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h\}
\end{align*}
Find $A − B$

I thought the answer could maybe be the empty set, because all of the elements of $A$ are in $B$ and the difference are the elements in $A$ that are not in $B$. But isn't the empty set in every set? So I have no idea what the answer is.

Comment: $A - B = \varnothing$, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think correctly.

Every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. Therefore $A-B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$ is empty.

The empty set is *a subset* of every set, it's not *an element* of every set. There is a big difference between the two notions.